# Why are these assassins everywhere I go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, every town I go to and just venture out in to the 'wilderness' I get ambushed by Hired thugs, or assassins. I kill them every time but it is really annoying, and lydia is still with me and I've commited a few minor crimes but always paid my bounty. What's HAPPENING?!

Answer (score 5):

The assassin is a random encounter. Starting from level 5 according to the [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Assassin).

The thugs are because you [stole](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hired_Thug) stuff. They are going to teach you a lesson, your actions have consequences in skyrim.

It is all part of the radiant quest system. Search for it on the wiki.